# First event/event relation insert taking a while

Tags: apex, event, performance, database, insert

I have an application that inserts events and event relations in an org's database and has a loading icon to prevent the user from doing anything until the event and relations are properly created and inserted.

However, the first event someone makes after going to the application can take a while (5-10 seconds). Then, they go quite quickly after that first one.

Looking at the timeline in the developer console of the create method that is being triggered, 79% of the 5 seconds (which is how long it took this last time I tried it) was spent in the Database, not my actual code. So it seems it was the inserts that were hanging things up.

Is there some way to speed that up? Would triggers that orgs have be included in 'database time'?

Here is a picture of what I mean from the timeline analysis:

[image]

Comment: When you say "go quickly after the first one" do you mean that you insert one at a time, and the first one takes five seconds and all subsequent inserts (also one at a time) go faster?

Comment: Yeah, The user creates an event, takes 5-10 seconds, it's created and the page is done loading. The user creates another event, takes a second. Looking at the timeline, it says 'Event Insert' 4,500ish ms.

Comment: Please post your code - both visualforce and controller, or the various lightning component parts. Also, if you have information on schema such as security settings and other pertinent info, please provide them.

Comment: Why would controller and visualforce code be necessary? Database time is not apex or visualforce code time. My code in either of those is not doing anything while it is inserting a record into the Database. And for Schema security settings... not entirely sure what you are looking for there. My user has complete read, write, access, delete permissions on events and event relations.

Comment: Because at first glance, there is no reason why anything would be the matter, so I'm expanding the considerations. 
Is this happening in Production and Sandbox? Developer org? Does it happen when you insert a record via the API/Data Loader? Anonymous Apex?

Comment: Assuming you don't have any complicated PB or workflow rules, it looks like it may be database contention. Are they adding items to parent records that see a lot of traffic (e.g. a heavily used account)?

Comment: I never really have a problem in my dev org. But it happens in production and sandbox orgs of users. These users do have PB and/or workflow rules going on  and triggers that are related to events and fire with event creation/updating. Not sure if items are being added to heavily trafficked parent records... Would PB and workflow stuff slow it down like that in the 'database'? And is SF Caching allowing it to be speedy for events made after the first?

Comment: Creating through the Salesforce interface, it seems to be fine. It just seems to be the Apex insert... But it is hard to test since after the first one, they go quickly and it is unclear when the cache or whatever will clear so that it will take a long time again on the first one. I closed the browser, reopened and logged in and made a new event and it was still quick because I had just recently made the first one that took a while :/

Comment: Digging in further, I see Apex Trigger trgEvent under the Event Insert that took 4.5 seconds, and it has an n/a duration. The other things under the Event Insert all have a duration that doesn't even add up to 100ms. It may be that?